# Removing double quotes in beginning & end of string in a pipe delimited line in perl

Tags: perl

I have a Line that is pipe delimited:

```
John |DEMME|"9 Snowy "" Court"|WERRIBEE|""VIC""
```

I split my line to each fields

```
@fields = split (/\|/, $_);
```

what I want is to remove the double quotes in the beginning/end of each fields
but it should retain the double quotes that are in between.

expected output

```
John |DEMME|9 Snowy "" Court|WERRIBEE|VIC
```

I also tried this

```
s/^\"|"$//g;
```

but what it does is it reads by line not but fields, so it will only remove the double qoutes which are at the beginnig and end of the line.

another scenario:

```
John |DEMME| "Shop 6A ""Atlantic on Coolum""|WERRIBEE|VIC
```

output should be

```
John |DEMME| Shop 6A "Pacific on Coolum"|WERRIBEE|VIC
```

I hope you guys can help me with this.

thank you very much

Comment: Shouldn't that be `John |DEMME|9 Snowy " Court|WERRIBEE|VIC`?

Comment: @ikegami nope it is okay thanks:)

Comment: @ikegami but what if I want the output like that,
what am I going to change in this regex?
s/(?:^|(?<=\|))"|"(?=$|\|)//g;

Comment: I'd go looking at Text::CSV_XS and use a pipe as your separator.

Comment: If `""` is an escaped `"`, I'd use Text::CSV_XS to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's reading by lines, then you could write:

```
s/(?:^|(?<=\|))"|"(?=$|\|)//g;
```

to remove `"` at the start of a line or after a `|`, or at the end of a line or before a `|`.

(The `(?<=...)` notation creates a zero-width positive "lookbehind" assertion, which in this case checks to see if there's a `|` preceding; the `(?=...)` notation creates a zero-width positive "lookahead" assertion, which in this case checks to see if there's a `|` or end-of-file following.)

Comment: thanks that was great! It worked!

but if it is not too much trouble to ask,
can you please at least help me understand your code, I really want to
learn perl regex.
thanks

Comment: @Soncire: Sure. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: (?:^|(?<=\|)) ->this part
"|" -> this part
(?=$|\|)  -> this part

:)

Comment: @Soncire: `"|"` actually isn't a part; `|` indicates alternation, and here the two alternands are `(?:^|(?<=\|))"` (which ends with `"`) and `"(?=$|\|)` (which starts with `"`). As for `(?:^|(?<=\|))` . . . `(?:...)` is just a grouping construct; for example, `(?:a|b)+` means "a string of one or more a's and b's" (whereas `a|b+` means "either a single a, or else a string of one or more b's). `^` means "start of string", and `|` I've already explained. `(?<=...)`, as I mentioned in my answer, is a lookbehind assertion, so `(?<=\|)` means "a position that is preceded by a pipe. So *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* `(?:^|(?<=\|))` means "either start-of-string, or right after a pipe". Similarly, `(?=...)`, as I mentioned in my answer, is a lookahead assertion, so `(?=$|\|)` means "either end-of-string, or right before a pipe".

Comment: thanks for giving up some time explaining it to me, I really appreciate it. Thanks man!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

try this one dude

```
my $_='John |DEMME|"9 Snowy "" Court"|WERRIBEE|""VIC""';

my @fields = split (/\|/, $_);

foreach my $item(@fields){
 $item=~s/^\"+//g;
 $item=~s/\"+$//g;
print "$item";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes could also be removed from each field using a `map` expression:

```
@fields = map { s/^"(.*)"$/$1/; $_  } split (/\|/, $_);
```

`split` breaks the line apart into a list, while the `map` applies the substitution to each member of the list.  To join them back up:

print join('|', @fields), "\n";